# this keyword vs obj name in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Wondering what the difference between the two code below. In the first case I used `this` to refer to the object and in the second case I used the object name. Although both works I was wondering whether there is any real difference between the two.

```
(function() {
var app = {
    init: function () {
        app.addLun('Hello');
    },
    addLun: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
};
});
})();
```

and

```
var app = {
    init: function () {
        this.addLun('Hello');
    },
    addLun: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
};
});
})();
```

Comment: I am not sure what that last line is in both of your examples.

Comment: `this` is the context that's invoking the current function. `app` is the specific object you've created.

Comment: They are both equivalent in the sense that they should throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Evert LOL I see you found the same issue as [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925514/this-keyword-vs-obj-name-in-javascript/17925568#comment26189378_17925514) :-P

Comment: @Neal: Ah yes looks like I did :)

Comment: @Evert ^_^ :-D **emoticons**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `this` and `app` are absolutely not the same. Take this (slightly contrived) example:

```
var app = {
    init: { 
        foo: function () {
            // Think 'this' is app? 
            this.addLun('Hello');
        }
    },
    addLun: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
};

var app2 = {
    init: { 
        foo: function () {
            app2.addLun('Hello');
        }
    },
    addLun: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
};

app2.init.foo(); // prints Hello
app.init.foo();  // error - no method called addLun
```

`this` is the current context, `app` is the object you have just created.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the context/scope of the function, so depending on how you call it, it could refer to `app`, `window`, or many other scopes...

`app` refers to the **actual** app object if it exists in that scope.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is difference. If you want to have more, that one instance of app object (for example, you can clone it with jQuery.extend()), you need to use second variant for correct work.

Comment: No.... no I will not clone it with jQuery...